# Project cannot be run on 5c after upgraded XCode to 8.3.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I just updated my XCode to 8.3.3 and my project cannot be run on iPhone 5c (10.3.3) because of this error:

```
Invalid bitcode signature
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, it runs fine on other simulators and devices. I have tried to clean and rebuild too.

Anyone has advise?

**Note:**

Bitcode is disabled in my project

Comment: try clean by removing derived data, clean build folder `cmd + shift +k`.

Comment: GREAT @vaibhav by removing derived data, clean and rebuild, now it works lol